# If closure of subalgebra $A$ which separates points vanishes nowhere, then $A$ contains constants

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a subalgebra of $C(K)$ that separates points of $K$, with $K$ a compact Hausdorff space.

If $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ vanishes nowhere, that is, if there exists $f \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}: f(x) \neq 0, \forall x \in K$, then I want to show that $\mathcal{A}$ contains constants.

**My attempt:**

1. I defined the set $D = \{(f(x), f(y)), f \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}\} $.
2. Proved that $D$ is a subalgebra of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
3. Proved that $D = \mathbb{R}^2$.
4. Since $(1,1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $(1,1) \in D$. So there exists $f \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}$ such that $f(x) = 1$, for some $x \in K$.

So the above shows $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ contains constants, but how do I bring them into $\mathcal{A}$ and finish the proof? If only $\mathcal{A}$ was a closed subalgebra of $C(K)$, that would be immediate, but it's not the case.

Comment: In 2) how are you defining multiplication on $\mathbb R^{2}$?.

Comment: I would hunt for the unit in $\mathcal{A}$, since it is an algebra, and hence needs to have a unit. Now, since it seems like your definition of a subalgebra does not involve having the same element $1$, I would suggest you use the nonvanishing for showing that this is actually the same $1$ (using that idempotent elements, which are candidates for units of subalgebras, project onto some subalgebra, corresponding to functions vanishing on a set)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an algebra under coordinatewise addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Enkidu: it seems your idea has got potential, but I wouldn't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $C[0,1]$ the subspace spanned by $e^{cx},c>0$ is an algebra which meets these requirements but it does not contain constants.

Comment: So the statement I want to prove is incorrect?

Comment: @user71487 Yes, your statement is not correct.